# Sum-up dates specified as strings

Tags: php, date

```
$date = '2012-07-25 00:05';
$delay = '25';
```

Is there an easy way to add $delay to $date? The result must be '2012-07-25 00:30'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
 $new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($date . " +" . $delay . " minutes"));
```

Here's another:

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P'.$delay.'i'));
$new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i')
```

Comment: DateTime example now included

Comment: And what if $delay is specified without ':' like this '0005' or '0025'?

Comment: use `intval()` to remove the leading zeros

Comment: I would use `str_replace()` to remove the `:` and the `intval()` to remove the leading zeros. That would be the simplest method.